# Can I have UIDatePicker pick dates earlier than 01/01/0001 AD/CE?

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

Is there any way to select negative years? (i.e. years in the BC era)

I am only able to scroll the year column to minimum of "1". However, I wish to allow selecting BC years, such as -100, -1000, etc.

Is this possible with the `UIDatePicker`?

I tried to set the `minimumDate` property of `UIDatePicker` to a negative year, but that didn't affect the UI of the date picker control. Following is my code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:-2000];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:2000];
NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

self.datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
self.datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
```

And here is the result, where I still can't select any year before "1":

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened on 3rd August 300 BC? Dates back then are hard to define this way. Is it even valid to talk about August seeing as it was named after Augustus who didn't live for another 300 years? I think in this case you're best just not worrying about the specific date and providing a "Year" picker that allows the user to enter a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This is exactly what I ended with (which is, a year picker for the BC era).